# GLSL, passing functions

Tags: glsl, webgl, processing

I wrote a simple Sphere Tracer in Processing (Java) and am porting it to WebGL / GLSL. When I wrote it in Processing I had a base class `Shape` and would extend it for specific shapes such as `Box`, `Plane`, `Sphere`, etc. Each specific shape had members that were relevant to it, for example `Sphere` instances had a radius, `Box` instances had a length vector, etc. In addition each had a shape specific distance function.

Unfortunately I cannot use classes like this in GLSL and so I made a single `struct` that can represent any shape (I refer to it as `Object` below):

```
struct Object {
    vec3 pos, len, nDir;
    float rad;
} objects[4];
```

Then I wrote a distance function for each kind of shape:

```
float boxSignedDist(Object inBox, vec3 inPos) {
    vec3 boxDelta = abs(inPos-inBox.pos)-inBox.len;
    return min(max(boxDelta.x, max(boxDelta.y, boxDelta.z)), 0.0)+length(max(boxDelta, 0.0));
}

float planeSignedDist(Object inPlane, vec3 inPos) {
    return dot(inPos-inPlane.pos, inPlane.nDir);
}

float roundBoxUnsignedDist(Object inRoundBox, vec3 inPos) {
    return length(max(abs(inPos-inRoundBox.pos)-inRoundBox.len, 0.0))-inRoundBox.rad;
}

float sphereSignedDist(Object inSphere, vec3 inPos) {
    return length(inPos-inSphere.pos)-inSphere.rad;
}
```

Now I have run into a different problem which is wrapping shape specific distance functions with another function such as a rotation, it is not obvious how to do this efficiently in GLSL. I added a member to `Object`, `int type`, and then made a few `#define`s for each shape I support at the moment:

```
#define BOX_SIGNED 1
#define PLANE_SIGNED 2
#define ROUNDBOX_UNSIGNED 3
#define SPHERE_SIGNED 4

struct Object {
    int type;
    vec3 pos, len, nDir;
    float rad;
} objects[4];
```

So that now I can write a rotation wrapper to a distance function like this:

```
float rotateY(Object inObject, vec3 inPos, float inRadians) {
    inPos -= inObject.pos;
    inObject.pos = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    float cRad = cos(inRadians);
    float sRad = sin(inRadians);

    if (inObject.type == BOX_SIGNED)
        return boxSignedDist(inObject, vec3(cRad*inPos.x-sRad*inPos.z, inPos.y, cRad*inPos.z+sRad*inPos.x));
    else if (inObject.type == PLANE_SIGNED)
        return planeSignedDist(inObject, vec3(cRad*inPos.x-sRad*inPos.z, inPos.y, cRad*inPos.z+sRad*inPos.x));
    else if (inObject.type == ROUNDBOX_UNSIGNED)
        return roundBoxUnsignedDist(inObject, vec3(cRad*inPos.x-sRad*inPos.z, inPos.y, cRad*inPos.z+sRad*inPos.x));
    else if (inObject.type == SPHERE_SIGNED)
        return sphereSignedDist(inObject, vec3(cRad*inPos.x-sRad*inPos.z, inPos.y, cRad*inPos.z+sRad*inPos.x));
    else
        return 0.0;
}
```

It seems ridiculous that this would be necessary, is there a better way to do it? It would be nice if `rotateY` could receive a function pointer to just call the appropriate function instead of the all the `else if`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GLSL is quite a limited language really. The compiler does a great job at optimizing certain things but isn't perfect.

A few things to remember:

- Local memory is expensive, both in just declaring and in access
- Dynamically indexed arrays are put in local memory.
- Arrays and objects are padded to align to 16 byte boundaries. An `int[4]` array takes the same memory as a `vec4[4]` array. Your `Object` should group `vec3`s with `float`s.
- There's no such thing as a function call. Everything is inlined.
- Arguments passed to functions are copied in and copied out. The complier doesn't always optimized out these copies when the functions are inlined. Keep as much global as possible.
- Switch statements don't have jump operators, they are expanded to nested if-statements.
- Divergence is a tricky thing to optimize out. Your `if (type == ...` code could be improved by constructing the rotated `inPos` beforehand, but I can't see a way around the if-statements. Perhaps you could write permutations of functions for each object type (or use macros) and trace the types in batches separately?

You might get some good ideas looking at what people have written for https://www.shadertoy.com/.

Finally, GLSL *subroutines* have a similar intent as function pointers, but are used on a global scale for all shader executions and won't help here.

Comment: Thank you for the information, still new to GLSL. I did not realize that functions would be inlined. Also it seems that switch statements are not allowed (in addition to non-constant loops) which is particularly frustrating. Last, calculating `inPos` beforehand is probably a good idea, thanks

Comment: @asimes aah yes, webgl doesn't have the features that the more recent desktop GLSL has, so no dynamic branching :(